# WebBrowser isn't working

Tags: c#

I have this code:

This is a button press:

```
int part = 0;
web.Navigate(loginURL.Text + "/auth/login");
wait.Enabled = true;
```

This is a timer "wait", with interval set to 6000:

```
if (part == 0)
            {
                part = 2;
                web.Document.GetElementById("idLoginUserName").SetAttribute("value", user);
                web.Document.GetElementById("idLoginPassword").SetAttribute("value", pass);
                web.Document.GetElementById("idLoginBtn").InvokeMember("click");
            }
            if (part == 2)
            {
                web.Navigate(fullURL.Text);
                part = 3;
            }
            if (part == 3)
            {
                web.Document.GetElementById("title").SetAttribute("value", title.Text);
            }
            if (part == 4)
            {
                web.Navigate("www.vbulletin.com/forum/auth/logout");
                part = 5;
            }
            if (part == 5)
            {
                part = 0;
                web.Navigate(loginURL.Text + "/auth/login");
            }
```

The button press works fine, however:

```
 web.Document.GetElementById("idLoginUserName").SetAttribute("value", user);
                    web.Document.GetElementById("idLoginPassword").SetAttribute("value", pass);
                    web.Document.GetElementById("idLoginBtn").InvokeMember("click");
```

does nothing. The text isn't changed, the button isn't clicked, etc. I've checked and double checked the IDs and it's right.

The loginURL.Text is [this](http://www.vbulletin.com/forum/auth/login)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess you try to access the *document* before navigation is completed, this works for me...

```
web.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    web.Document.GetElementById("idLoginUserName").SetAttribute("value", user);
    web.Document.GetElementById("idLoginPassword").SetAttribute("value", pass);
    web.Document.GetElementById("idLoginBtn").InvokeMember("click");
};
web.Navigate("http://www.vbulletin.com/forum/auth/login");
```

Answer (score -3):

You are not obliged to do everything using C#. If you treat the embedded web page as a black box fro the point of view of your app, you can give it internal behaviours using scripts, and jQuery makes this sort of thing short, sweet and very legible for those who come after, with the added benefit of not polluting application logic with functionally trivial but frequently complex UI behaviour code.

```
$(function(){
  $("#idLoginUserName").val(user);
  $("#idLoginPassword").val(password);
  $("#idLoginBtn").click();
});
```

Comment: And on the ninth day, people noticed the question was tagged `c#` and it was related to call the js in `Webbrowser` Control.

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice the C# tag, but use of C# is probably *not* a deliverable. Will my solution work in the WebBrowser control? Yes, it will. Is my suggestion likely to work? Yes, it is. Is it short, sweet and portable? Yep. Is it compatible with hosting in an app? Sure.

Comment: The url is there, instead of writing  a lot of bla bla, post a working code that downloads that page, fills the fields and executes the script. that would be more helpful....