# GetElementByID isn't working

Tags: c#, getelementbyid

I have this code:

```
web.Document.GetElementById("idLoginUserName").SetAttribute("value", user);
```

User is a string, web is a WebBrowser control. it's under

```
private void web_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
```

This is the ID on the page:

```
<input tabindex="100" type="text" name="username" id="idLoginUserName" value="" class="textbox ">
```

Yet I get this error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MyProgram.exe

An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MyProgram.exe but was not handled in user code
```

Debugging it, I can see that it does try to execute it, and it returns with that error right as it tries.

Comment: Have you tried to use `DocumentCompleted` event instead of `Navigated`, as answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048920/webbrowser-isnt-wokring) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18050820/1906557)

Comment: Yes, I changed it from DocumentCompleted after it didn't work.

Comment: Are you able to determine exactly which value is `null`? Debuggers are handy.

Comment: I debugged it and didn't see anything being null, but I'm not very good at debugging so I may be simply missing something.

Comment: @Minicl55 this code works `string html2 = @"<input tabindex=""100"" type=""text"" name=""username"" id=""idLoginUserName"" value="""" class=""textbox "">";
    web.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        web.Document.GetElementById("idLoginUserName").SetAttribute("value", "XYZ");
    };
    web.DocumentText = html2;` So your bug must be somewhere else...

Comment: @Minicl55 And if you changed the event to `Navigated` in my previous example, you'll get *NullReferenceException*

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if web is null.

Check to see if web.Document is null.

Check to see if web.Document.GetElementById("idLoginUserName") returns null.

Check to see if user is null.

It has to be one of those or the error is coming from somewhere else.